# Copy worksheets from all open workbooks & paste into new master workbook - revised

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have the following code courtesy of get.digital.help.com

Code executes fine except for 2 things:

1. the personal.xlsb file pastes into new master wrkbk along with all the other open wrkbks.

   How can code prevent personal.xlsb from being copied.
2. error code "*Run time error 9: Subscript is out of range*" generated at this line located just before "end macro"/ "end sub":

**WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete**

What is causing this error and how to fix it?

```vb
'Name macro
'https://www.get-digital-help.com/copy-each-sheet-in-active-workbook-to-new-workbooks/#master

Sub CopySheetsToMasterWorkbook()

'this version includes option to name copied worksheets

'Dimension variables and declare data types
Dim WBN As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Dim SHT As Worksheet
 'Create a new workbook and save an object reference to variable WBN
Set WBN = Workbooks.Add
'Iterate through all open workbooks
For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
'Check if workbook name of object variable WB is not equal to name of object variable WBN
If WB.Name <> WBN.Name Then
'Go through all worksheets in object WB
For Each SHT In WB.Worksheets
'Copy worksheet to workbook WBN and place after the last worksheet
SHT.Copy After:=WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count)
'Adds option to name each WrkSht added to MasterWB
WBN.Sheets(WBN.Worksheets.Count).Name = Left(WB.Name, 30 - Len(SHT.Name)) & "-" & SHT.Name
'Continue with next worksheet
Next SHT
'End of If statement
End If
'Continue with next workbook
Next WB
'Disable Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
**'Delete sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 in the new workbook WBN
WBN.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete**
'Enable Alerts
WBN.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'End macro
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I modify the code to activate each of the 11 open workbooks (without hard coding specific file names for the source workbooks -- which I believe would require re-naming each wrkbk first).

Pattern:

```
Const destination_name As String = "Destination.XLSX"
Dim destination As Workbook

Sub processworkbooks()
' .....
    Set destination = Application.Workbooks(destination_name)
    For Each OneWorkbook In Application.Workbooks 
        If OneWorkbook.Name <> destination_name Then
            Call CopySheet(OneWorkbook)
        End If
    Next
' .....
End Sub

Sub CopySheet(source As WorkBook)
    For Each OneSheet In source.Sheets
        OneSheet.Copy After:=destination.Sheets(destination.Sheets.Count)
    Next    
End Sub
```

The code copies all sheets from all opened workbooks (except destination one) into destination workbook.

Comment: I created a workbook called destination.xlsx and ran above macro. Error msg occurs at Sub processworkbooks()  Compile error:ByRef argument type mismatch. Fix? h/t Akina

Comment: 1) It is a pattern, not a final code. 2) Have you added OneWorkbook variable definition?  3) Does workbook called destination.xlsx was opened? in the same Excel instance strongly...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. What is the "OneWorkbook variable def"? The destination.xlsx was opened when macro ran.  Will the OneWorkbook variable def call open workbooks when macro is run. Thanks very much!

Comment: *What is the "OneWorkbook variable def"?* `OneBook` variable is used as iterational variable for `Application.Workbooks` collection. The type of elements in this collection is `Workbook`, so `Dim OneBook As Workbook` in the body of `Sub processworkbooks()`.